# In memory sqlite always empty despite setup

Tags: sqlite, symfony, doctrine, phpunit, functional-testing

I followed sitepoints [Testing Symfony Apps with a Disposable Database](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-testing-symfony-apps-with-a-disposable-database/) Tutorial.
I added Fixtures in my Testcase and no Errors appear during SetUp. If i add an Error in the Fixtures (*e.g. leaving a nullable=false field empty*) the Error is shown, so this code does definitely get executed.

My Config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: memory
        connections:
            memory:
                driver: pdo_sqlite
                memory: true
                charset: UTF8
```

My SetUp in my WebTestCase:

```
protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    self::bootKernel();
    DatabasePrimer::prime(self::$kernel);
    $this->loadFixtures([
        'AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\UserData',
        'AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\ArtistData'
    ]);
}
```

Yet, in my WebTestCase it appears that no Tables exist.
The output throws a Doctrine Exception saying my table does not exist.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: my_user_table
```

If i switch to sql_lite in a file, everything works fine without any other changes:

```
dbal:
    default_connection: file
    connections:
        file:
            driver:   pdo_sqlite
            path:     %kernel.cache_dir%/test.db
            charset: UTF8
```

Anyone had success with said tutorial or using a sqlite memory db for unit tests and has any hints or ideas?

**Update:**
I changed my Setup to this to ensure the kernel is not shut down in between. It did not help:

```
parent::setUp();
$this->client = $this->getClient();
MemoryDbPrimer::prime(self::$kernel);
$this->loadFixtures([
    'AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\UserData',
    'AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\ArtistData'
]);
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the connection name from `memory`, e.g `default_connection: memory` to `default_connection: default` or some other name? it may be that using that reserved word (as it's a property within the connection data itself) is causing an issue. It might be worth posting your fixture file also.

Comment: @JohnJoseph: I tried that, yet it made no difference. My fixtures file is quite large so i'd rather not do that.
Also, since it works in sqllte file more, i doubt that my fixtures are the problem.

Comment: I still think your kernel somehow gets shutdown/rebooted in between. To find out where, you can add `print("bootKernel() called\n"); debug_print_backtrace();` at the top of the `bootKernel()` function in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php` and then run one of the affected test cases.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for your problem? I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 6):

When you

```
$client->request(<METHOD>, <URL>);
```

which calls

```
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundleClient::doRequest($request)
```

After the request the kernel is shutdown by default, and your in-memory database is trashed.

If you call

```
client->disableReboot();
```

in the setup() function of your test, this will behavior is disabled, and you can run the whole suite.

Comment: $this->client->disableReboot(); 

this was the missing piece for me - preventing the TableNotFoundException I was getting.

Comment: client->disableReboot();  ... manno ... 4 hours digged around for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you call `createClient()` in your test functions. The very first thing that `createClient()` does is call `static::bootKernel()`. This basically means that the kernel you booted in your `setUp()` gets shut down and a new kernel is booted, with a fresh instance of the memory SQLite database.

You can move the `createClient()` call into your `setUp()`, replacing the `bootKernel()`, to avoid this:

```
class MyTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $client = null;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
        // prime database
    }

    public function testSomething()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Point, yet, this is already done in my Tests: ````protected function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->client = $this->makeClient(); ...````

Comment: Maybe you should show us one of your test functions.